# pySerial read missing bits

Tags: python, pyserial

I have the following write and read code for the serial port. But when I run them frequently, say 100 times write and read, there's always some times the read got wrong byte number, it should get 9 bytes, but sometimes it got only 8 bytes.

For example, normally when I send,  [1, 88, 0, 27, 192], it should return 9 bytes, like  [1, 88, 4, 0, 0, 3, 35, 182, 49]. But it always wrong at the number 89 times of write and read, it returns like [1, 88, 4, 0, 1, 209, 107, 180], 1 byte less. And after I detect this is 1 byte missing, I write and read the same sending message again like [1, 88, 0, 27, 192], the read data after this is always having one byte missing. However, after some other statements in between, the 1 byte missing problem won't appear every time.

I have got another problem like, the device cannot received my write sometimes on specific command, to be specific, there's no returns after I send a command when there should be, and since my serial device didn't receive so it doesn't execute. So I have to close() and open() such port and send command again for several times, to make is returns aka excute the command, such retries take so much time which makes me anoying waiting.

My configuration, FT232RL USB to Serial chip, 9600 baud rate, 8 bytesize, timeout is 1 second, stop bits 1, parity None.

```
def SendData(self, portID, cmd):
        """
        cmd is the pre-defined variables , they are the lists in front of this file.
        After send data, there is a delay.
        """
        global command_count
        if (self.isOpen(portID)):
            command_count += 1
            lock = threading.RLock()
            with lock:
                try:
                    COMlogger.debug("SendData command count %d" % (command_count))
                    writereturn = self.serdict[portID].write(list2bytestr(cmd))
                    # wait for output buffer to drain, reference from the miniterm example
                    self.serdict[portID].flush()
                    self.lastcmd = cmd
                    COMlogger.debug("SendData sent out %s" % (str(cmd)))
                    COMlogger.debug("SendData write returns %d bytes." % writereturn)
                except:
                    COMlogger.error("Sending data to %s with ID %d failed." % (self.portaddresslist[portID], portID))
                    return False
                finally:
                    time.sleep(0.2)

            return True
        return False

    def GetData(self, portID):
        """
        It take times to let the device respond, so remember to wait a bit after sending data.
        Before get data, there is a deley
        """
        time.sleep(0.2)
        global command_count
        if (self.isOpen(portID)):
            lock = threading.RLock()
            with lock:
                try:
                    # possibly time out here
                    #receivedmsg = self.serdict[portID].readline() # stop using readline since it wait for the \n or time out.
                    text = self.serdict[portID].read(1)
                    if text:
                        time.sleep(0.2)
                        n = self.serdict[portID].inWaiting()
                        if n:
                            text += self.serdict[portID].read(n)
                    receivedmsg = text
                    COMlogger.debug("GetData from ID %d returned %s" %(portID, str(bytestr2list(receivedmsg))))
                    return receivedmsg
                except:
                    COMlogger.error( "Receiving data from %s with ID %d failed." % (self.portaddresslist[portID], portID))
                    return None
        else:
            COMlogger.error("Error in GetData, port %d is not open." % portID)
        return None
```

Comment: My best guess is that you have a clock issue. But there are not enough information to make a good analysis: what do you expect when you find a byte less? I mean that it not clear if you expect *exactly* `[1, 88, 4, 0, 1, 209, 107, 180]` or something like this.

Comment: [1, 88, 4, 0, 1, 209, 107, 180] is the wrong return in my description. And I guess the first several bytes are right, the format is actually [Device Address, Command Index, Following Data Bytes number, Left Most Byte, Byte 2, Byte 3, Right Most Byte, CRC High, CRC Low]. So I guess [1,88,4,0,1] is actually right, the problem is the last serveral bytes don't mean anything. So that's why I say, it maybe lose some bits.

Comment: Sorry , my mistake. I wanted to write `[1, 88, 4, 0, 0, 3, 35, 182, 49]` instead. Can you give exactly what you expect to receive in bytes when you receive one byte left. I'm asking that because if you have a clock issue you will lost a bit every x bytes and so lost a byte (last 7 bits byte will be ignored). If you lost a bit the result should be shifted to left of 1 bit in the middle of the message. So know what you should receive and what you really receive is the key to say if you have a clock issue or not.

Comment: Moreover in your fail example 180 is not the hight part of CRC so that will exclude that you lost last byte but maybe something in the middle.